# How to restore my hdd?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

My 1TB HDD sudenly dissapeared from my laptop, bought in October. It is not visible from Disk Manager screen. Reseting computer and deleting last Windows 10 update did nothing.

Lately, it wasn't exposed to any damage, but this one time, couple moths ago, i droped it (laptop) from about 30-40 cm, on the floor, when it was "running". I had problems with it since, but wery periodically. About a month back, files started dissapearing from d: partition, which is allocated on this drive. After reset, files were showing up again. I formated the drive, and all things went back to normal, until now. Is my hdd broken? How to check it? And if possible, how to restore it?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure.

Comment: Probably defective now. Is it an internal drive or external USB enclosure?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - The author dropped the HDD while it was running.  That sort of excludes it being an internal drive (unless they mean they dropped the entire laptop).

Comment: @Ramhound Not necessarily. It could have been an internal drive banging out the tower. I had one like that for a while (testing,, intended to be used in another machine) and it suffered similar fate :) Yes, it was as good as dead afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, I dropped the entire laptop, sorry for mistake.

Comment: @StanisławRichardt - Between the fact you dropped the entire laptop, suffered data loss, it is obvious the HDD has suffered from that happening.  The HDD has failed.  You should replace it.

Comment: Now, assuming it's an external drive, a regular HDD in a USB enclosure, there are two possibilities: Failure of the drive itself or failure of the USB-SATA interface adapter. We can only test it by trial and error. This means removing the HDD from the enclosure, connecting it directly to a SATA port and see if it's recognized.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, but you could never be sure, unless you check it. My question is: is there a way to diagnose it from software (maybe cmd?)? And if yes, how to do it?

Comment: @StanisławRichardt - You don't specify the HDD manufacture.  Most OEM HDD software only allows you to test their hardware.  However, the fact it is not showing up at all within Windows is an indication the drive has failed.  The data loss was another indication.

Comment: If you did a fast format, try doing a "slow" format.

Answer (score 1):

Even if working, a hard-drive may fail intermittently after it suffered physical damage until it stops completely. Sometimes there are shards that broke off when it was damaged that roam inside the hard-drive that produce these random issues (as some failures are recoverable, so the HD just "fixes" the bad data and marks the area as a bad block) until these shards end up damaging the hard-drive to the point it is not operable anymore and further bad blocks can't be recovered anymore.

You may "resuscitate" the hard-drive after with some persistence (power cycle a few times, try to re-seat it in the motherboard...). Once you get back to your files, copy everything out and decommission the hard-drive as storage ASAP.